# Solve in integers the equation $\sqrt{x^3-3xy^2+2y^3}=\sqrt[3]{13x+8}$

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations, integers

> Solve in integers the equation 
>   $$\sqrt{x^3-3xy^2+2y^3}=\sqrt[3]{13x+8}$$

#### My work so far:

I used [www.wolframalpha.com](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sqrt(x%5E3-3xy%5E2%2B2y%5E3)%3D(13x%2B8)%5E(1%2F3)). Then $x=9,y=8 -$ solution.

#### My attempt:

1) Let $\sqrt{x^3-3xy^2+2y^3}=a, \sqrt[3]{13x+8}=b$. Then 
$$\begin{cases}
a=b\\
a^2-b^3=x^3-3xy^2+2y^3-13x-8 \in \mathbb Z
\end{cases}$$

2) $$(x^3-3xy^2+2y^3)^3=(13x+8)^2$$

#### Addition:

We have $$A^6\cdot B^6=(13x+8)^2$$
and $$n^6 \equiv 0, \pm 1 (\bmod 13)$$

Comment: I don't know if this could help, but $x^3-3xy^2+2y^3\equiv(x-y)(x^2+xy-2y^2)$

Comment: $\equiv(x-y)^2(x+2y)$

Comment: so $|x-y|\sqrt{x+2y}=\sqrt[3]{13x+8}$

Comment: Hence, $x+2y=k^2$ and $13x+8=m^3$?

Comment: @Roman83 exactly

Comment: The substitution $z:=x-y$ makes the equation cubic in $x$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are no integer solutions with $x<0$, since $13x+8<0$ for such $x$. When $0\leq x\leq 8$ then $13x+8$ is not an integer cubic. Since the latter is easily seen to be a necessary condition it follows that there are no solutions with $x$ in this range. On the other hand you already have found the solution $(9,8)$. In the following I shall prove that there are no solutions with $x\geq10$.

I'm considering $x\geq10$ as "primary variable" and write $y:=x-t$ with a new  integer variable $t$. The equation at stake then reads
$$a:=\sqrt{t^2(3x-2t)}=\root 3\of{13x+8}=:b\ .$$
If $t\leq-1$ then
$$a=|t|\sqrt{3x+2|t|}\geq\sqrt{3x}\ .$$
For $x=10$ we therefore have $a^3\geq\bigl(\sqrt{3x}\bigr)^3=30^{3/2}>164>138=13x+8=b^3$, and things get worse for larger $x$.

If $t=1$ and $x=10$ then $a=\sqrt{3x-2}=\sqrt{28}$.
For $x=10$ we therefore have $a^3\geq28^{3/2}>148>138=b^3$, and things get worse for larger $x$.

If $2\leq t\leq x$ then
$$a\geq2\sqrt{3x-2t}\geq2\sqrt{x}\ .$$
For $x=10$ we therefore have $a^3\geq8\cdot10^{3/2}>252>138=b^3$, and things get worse for larger $x$.

Finally, if $2x\leq 2t\leq 3x-1$ then
$$a=\sqrt{t^2(3x-2t)}=t\sqrt{3x-2t}\geq x\ .$$
For $x=10$ we therefore have $a^3\geq10^3>138$, and things get worse for larger $x$.